# C#: backing field declaration and summary tag

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide

When defining properties I like to do just before property declaration, something like this

```
private IList<SomeType> _myList;
public IEnumerable<SomeType> MyList
{
   get { return _myList;}
}
```

But if I place `///<summary>` tag on the property, I lose the benefit of declaring the backing fields like this, it is not readable any more. If I place it before backing field, comments do not show in the IDE. Is there a way to put summary tag before backing field and have it show up in IDE (VS2008)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `/// <summary>` tag has to be placed just before the element it is describing.

You can try and put the field just *after* the property:

```
/// <summary>
public IEnumerable<SomeType> MyList
{
  get { return _myList;}
}
private IList<SomeType> _myList;
```

If the backing field is not essential (only used the same way as your example), you can simply use [automatic properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx):

```
/// <summary>
public IEnumerable<SomeType> MyList
{
  get;
}
```

Comment: Just as I thought, just wanted to make sure there was not some hidden gem.

Answer (score 0):

With automatic properties, this has become less of a concern to me; I have taken to putting any explicit backing fields that I need in a group separated from the properties.